# How to return falsy from a React component?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to return a falsy from React component?

```
const Foo = () => null

// here is React object (instead of null), which is truthy
console.log('Foo', <Foo />);
```

Comment: React component must return either JSX or null

Comment: @user0101 thats not true, for example, a string is a valid component too. https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#booleans-null-and-undefined-are-ignored

Comment: Still JSX, right?

Comment: @user0101 `const App = () => "Im not JSX";` , is not JSX, you said it must return JSX or `null`, that's all. Also `ReactDOM.render("I'm clearly not JSX", document.getElementById("root"));` will work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSX is a [sugar syntax](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Syntactic_sugar#:~:text=In%20computer%20science%2C%20syntactic%20sugar,style%20that%20some%20may%20prefer.) for `React.createElement`.

> In computer science, syntactic sugar is syntax within a programming language that is designed to make things easier to read or to express.

```
<Foo />

// Transpiles to
React.createElement(Foo, null);

// Normal function call which returns null
// Won't "register" Foo component to React tree
// because no createElement invoked
Foo();
```

So by constructing JSX you can't return anything than an object which is truthy.

- [JSX in Depth](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html)
- [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement)
- [JSX babel playground](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwMQ9mAED0B8Q&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.10.2&externalPlugins=)